# Is there any way to check whether a task or message exists in Rabbitmq queue ? The idea is to eliminate duplicate tasks going into the queue

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, rabbitmq

I am saving file names in task or message in rabbitmq queue. I want to make sure that there is no duplicate task with same filename created. Is there any way to make sure that rabbitmq rejects duplicates or at least check whether that filename exists or not in queue?

Following is the code :

```
ch.assertQueue(insertImg, { durable: true }).then(() => {
ch.sendToQueue(insertImg, Buffer.from(zipFileName));
resolve();
})


ch.assertQueue(insertImg, { durable: true }).then(async () => {
await ch.prefetch(1);
return ch.consume(insertImg, async function (fileName) {}, { noAck: false });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

RabbitMQ queue content cannot be easily inspected. Only feasible way would be to fetch all messages contained within and check them on the consumer side.

If message deduplication is what you are looking for, there is a [plugin](https://github.com/noxdafox/rabbitmq-message-deduplication) for discarding duplicate messages on the broker.